# Why jQuery ui tabs are not working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-ui-theme

I found the same question here [jquery ui tabs not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232668/jquery-ui-tabs-not-working) but it didn't help me. This is my HTML which should create the tabs but it's not working:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Tabs</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.ui.all.css">
    <script src="jquery-1.7.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.ui.tabs.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
        });
   </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Content 1.</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Content 2.</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Content 3.</p>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and output of this html is this:

```
     . Nunc tincidunt
     . Proin dolor
     . Aenean lacinia
 Content 1.

 Content 2.

 Content 3.
```

list elements should be displayed as tabs but they displaying as list. Why is that so? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you js files loading correctly? Can you put a console.log statement before $( "#tabs" ).tabs(); to ensure that LOC is being run?

Comment: i did that. i put alerts before and after $( "#tabs" ).tabs(); and its working

Comment: Is the path to your jQuery UI css correct?

Comment: did you get any solution for this ??Me too facing same problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you haven't found an answer, this is caused by either old or mismatched jQuery/jQuery-ui versions.  Update both and should work like a charm!

Answer (score 6):

Most likely your jQuery is executing before the DOM is loaded, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#tabs").tabs();

});
```

Comment: $(function() { }) is shorthand for $(document).ready(function () { })

Answer (score 1):

Try to use these scripts instead of yours (just replace the bottom lines):

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function() {
           $("#tabs").tabs();
       });
   </script>
```

Also change the CSS file source to this one:

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

I'm guessing you are not specifying well the JS Source for jQuery's. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

HTML is parsed top-down. Your function refers to an ID called `tabs` before it is rendered.

It is also not clear from your imports that your JQuery dependencies are all at the same version.

Here is a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
</head>
<body>

  <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-2">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-3">3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
      <p>Text 1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
      <p>Text 2</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
      <p>Text 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  } );
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note the following:

1. The JQuery UI theme in the `<head>` tag. I have used "base" for this example.
2. The main JQuery JS file, moved to the bottom of the script and declared before the JQuery UI extension JS file.
3. The JQuery UI extension JS file, moved to the bottom of the script and declared after the main JQuery JS file.
4. The block of Javascript which calls the tabs function on the container has been moved to a position the script after the container has been created in HTML and after the JQuery JS dependencies have been loaded.
5. All version numbers agree for the JQuery dependencies.

Answer (score -1):

It is [best practice](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom) to link to the scripts as close to the end of the body as possible.

The script is running before the HTML has loaded, so when you call `$("#tabs").tabs()` there is no element with an `id` of `tabs` on the page yet.

Try moving the scripts to the end of the page and see if that helps:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Tabs</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
       </ul>
       <div id="tabs-1">
           <p>Content 1.</p>
       </div>
       <div id="tabs-2">
           <p>Content 2.</p>
       </div>
       <div id="tabs-3">
           <p>Content 3.</p>
       </div>
   </div>
   <script src="jquery-1.7.js"></script>
   <script src="jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
   <script src="jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
   <script src="jquery.ui.tabs.js"></script> 
   <script>
       $(function() {
           $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
       });
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: missing jquery.ui.base.css but it doesn't make any difference. once i added all css. it didn't help. it should show tabs atleast. styling is something different. isn't it?

Comment: yeah, it should still work with no styling at all. Look at the rendered HTML in Firebug or similar, the elements within the tabs container should be getting classnames like 'ui-widget-content' and others prefixed with 'ui' - is this the case? Also Try removing the href from the links and the id from the divs (except the outer div) - the tabs widget should add these for you.

Answer (score -1):

Make completely sure that you are not loading the jquery javascript twice in your page. If you are loading it more than once or loading 2 different versions of the script, it will cause this problem.

Answer (score -2):

I had this same problem, and this solved it for me:

`<a href="#divdata" data-ajax="false">link</a>`

Answer (score -3):

Your forgot to call jquery-ui script :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What do you think `<script src="jquery.ui.core.js"></script>` and the two scripts after it are?